# Looping inside variable (json data)

Tags: javascript, json

Anyone know how looping json data INSIDE varibale?? Example

```
var data = {

                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            console.log(data[i].PageName);
                        });​

                        labels: [dateLoop],
                        datasets: [{

                        }]
                };
```

Well that code is didnt work for me. I want looping inside that varibale. Anyway this coding for Chart.js

Why i need looping?? cuase i have filter buyer and date range, if i choose 3 buyer, and date range from january 2016 to May 2016. On data will show data buyer, each data buyer will have value from date range. Exmaple data json

```
data [Buyer 1] : ["167404", "129770", "113598", "127301", "156868", "634789", "242188", "166312", "169418"];
data [Buyer 2] : ["9580", "22250", "3500", "5558", "254556", "268500", "77750", "69850", "55"];
```

So what i need how too looping inside variable?? Sorry my bad languange.

Edit probbaly someone dont know what i mean,
example i have pick 2 buyer, Buyer A (Json["data"][0]) and Buyer B (Json["data"][1]) and each that buyer have value (wich this value order by month if i pick January and May, it will show "222","555")
 and the code i mean like this :

```
var data = {

  labels: [dateLoop], #ignore this

  datasets: [{ label :  (Json["data"][0])

                           fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",

strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

pointStrokeColor: "#fff",

pointHighlightFill: "#fff",

pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

data: [(value orderby month in Json["data"][0]]       

  },

{ label :  (Json["data"][1])

                           fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",

strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

pointStrokeColor: "#fff",

pointHighlightFill: "#fff",

pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

data: [(value orderby month in Json["data"][1]]       

  }

]

    };
```

That i want it. But i sue each make error. :/

Comment: `data` is an object and it need to have key value pair. loop inside it is not possible. You can create  a method  and call the method

Comment: You have code inside your json ? Is it what you are trying to do ?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. What is `data` exactly? I can see that there should be something like a `data` array with element properties like `PageName`. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide the array structure?

Comment: @Weedoze yes, i have code inside json

Comment: @user2181397 well that method, i'm using chart.js, then i use this method for filter and show that chart. :3

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need 2 loop first loop is for keys and second is for the values inside array

```
var data = {
        'Buyer 1': ["167404", "129770", "113598", "127301", "156868", "634789", "242188", "166312", "169418"],
        'Buyer 2': ["9580", "22250", "3500", "5558", "254556", "268500", "77750", "69850", "55"]
    }
for(var key in data) {
    for (var x in data[key]) {
        console.log(data[key][x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe u didnt understanding what i mean, i'm use CHART.JS format, so if i use coding like that probally is show error.